# How to access CAN signals dynamically (by string) in CAPL?

Tags: com, can-bus, capl, canoe, canalyzer

I'm trying to force CAN signals to given values using COM interface of CANalyzer. Since there is no COM method to send CAN messages, I'm implementing a workaround using CAPL:

```
void SendMySignal(int value) {
  message MyMessage msg;
  msg.MySignal = value;
  output(msg);
}
```

This works fine, however since `MyMessage` and `MySignal` are referenced statically (by name) here, I'll have to implement N functions to be able to send N signals (or an N-way switch statement, etc). Is there a way to avoid the hassle and access signals inside a message by string? Something like this:

```
void SendSignal(int MessageID, char SignalName, int value)
```

I'm also open to alternative solutions in case I have missed something in the COM interface. If there is a solution which only works for CANoe, I can ask my boss for a license, but of course I'd prefer to do without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is such function, but it is restricted to be used **only in test nodes**

```
long setSignal(char signalName[], double aValue);
```

you can find details in:

> CAPL Function Overview » Test Feature Set / Signal Access » SetSignal 
>       Special Use Case: Signal is not known before Measurement Start

and take care about not to send for each signal a new message to avoid bus over-flooding. In my opinion it is a better style to set all signals for whole message and to send it on change **only when it is not cyclic**. Signal updates in cyclic messages **mostly** have to be sent in next cycle.